# Specific regex to match different cases

Tags: regex, data-cleaning

I am working on finding **ONE** regex for the following expressions:

"AAA_AAA**_**Bbb_Bbb"

"AAA_AAA**_**bbb_bbb"

"AAA_Bbb**_**Bbb"

"AAA_bbb_bbb"

B are capital letters.

b are either letters or numbers.

I need to take every B/b and every underscore between them.

I used this regex: "([a-z0-9\s+]{1,})" to try to match my expressions but it does not take into account the capital B.

The expected result is "Bbb_Bbb" or "bbb_bbb".

Do you have any idea on how to do it?

Thank you in advance for your help. I am at your disposal should you need more information.

KR,

a'

Comment: This is not quite clear. Do you just want to add uppercase letters to the regex? `[A-Za-z0-9_\s]+` / `[\w\s]+`?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I need to take everything except the uppercase letters at the beginning of the expression. I managed to do that with my Regex but I also need to include the cases where there are some uppercase letters within the second part of the expression.

Comment: I am not sure what the expected result is. Please edit the question to include them

Comment: Maybe you need `^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*`? See https://regex101.com/r/0OLsN4/1

Comment: I added the expected results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor for your prompt answer. I would need the second part of the expression and not the first part.

Comment: So, why not `.replace(/^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*_/, '')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/0OLsN4/2))?

Comment: Of course, you may as well use `^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*_\K.*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0OLsN4/4)

Comment: Actually, I just used a replace with a simpler regex: "([A-Z]{1,}[_])" and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace

```
^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*_
```

with an empty string. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0OLsN4/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]+` - 1+ uppercase letters
- `(?:_[A-Z]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `_` and then 1+ uppercase letters
- `_` - a `_` char.